# Removing a symbol from td cell not working

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a column that has $ signs and i want all the $ signs removed and just leave the raw number

setup a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ryc84j6n/

not sure why neither of these wont work

```
$('td.salary').each(function() {
    //$(this).text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '');
    $(this).text().replace("$", "");
});
```

html

```
<td class="salary">$1</td>
```

Comment: the syntax is:  $(this).text( $(this).text().replace("$", "")  );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the text to the new value.

```js
$('td.salary').each(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color","red");
  let textWithoutDollarSign = $(this).text().replace("$", "");
  $(this).text(textWithoutDollarSign);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center" cellspacing="1" class="report franchise_0002" id="roster">
   <caption><span><a title="Franchise home page, Record: 0-0-0, PF: 78.06" class="franchise_0002 " href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;F=0002&amp;O=07">Franchise 2</a></span></caption>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="player">Player</th>
         <th class="points">Pts</th>
         <th class="week">Bye</th>
         <th class="salary">Salary</th>
         <th class="contractstatus">Notes</th>
         <th class="contractinfo">Year Signed</th>
         <th class="drafted">Acq.</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddtablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=15252" title="Salary: $3, Notes: RFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: vs Jaguars Sun 1:00 p.m. ET" class="position_qb">Mills, Davis HOU QB<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsNew.svg" alt="new news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="new news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a></td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=15252&amp;YEAR=2022">10.38</a></td>
         <td class="week">6</td>
         <td class="salary">$3</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">RFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">5.06</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="eventablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=15698" title="Salary: $1, Notes: UFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: at Raiders Sun 4:05 p.m. ET" class="position_qb">Purdy, Brock SFO QB<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsOld.svg" alt="recent news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="recent news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a> (R) </td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=15698&amp;YEAR=2022">18.06</a></td>
         <td class="week">9</td>
         <td class="salary">$1</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">UFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">BB $173</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddtablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=9431" title="Salary: $2, Notes: RFA, Year Signed: 2021, Week 17: at Chargers Sun 4:25 p.m. ET" class="position_qb">Stafford, Matthew LAR QB<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsNone.svg" alt="no news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="no news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a> (<span class="warning injurystatus" title="IR">I</span>)</td>
         <td class="points"> ‐ </td>
         <td class="week">7</td>
         <td class="salary">$2</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">RFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2021</td>
         <td class="drafted">4.16 (2021)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="eventablerow newposition ">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=15719" title="Salary: $1, Notes: UFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: vs Dolphins Sun 1:00 p.m. ET" class="position_rb">Harris, Kevin NEP RB<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsOld.svg" alt="recent news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="recent news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a> (R) </td>
         <td class="points"> ‐ </td>
         <td class="week">10</td>
         <td class="salary">$1</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">UFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">BB $0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddtablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=15717" title="Salary: $3, Notes: RFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: vs Jaguars Sun 1:00 p.m. ET" class="position_rb">Pierce, Dameon HOU RB<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsNone.svg" alt="no news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="no news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a> (R)  (<span class="warning injurystatus" title="IR">I</span>)</td>
         <td class="points"> ‐ </td>
         <td class="week">6</td>
         <td class="salary">$3</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">RFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">1.06</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="eventablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=15709" title="Salary: $3, Notes: RFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: vs Rams Sun 4:25 p.m. ET" class="position_rb">Spiller, Isaiah LAC RB<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsNone.svg" alt="no news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="no news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a> (R) </td>
         <td class="points"> ‐ </td>
         <td class="week">8</td>
         <td class="salary">$3</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">RFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">2.06</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddtablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=15710" title="Salary: $3, Notes: RFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: at Chargers Sun 4:25 p.m. ET" class="position_rb">Williams, Kyren LAR RB<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsOld.svg" alt="recent news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="recent news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a> (R) </td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=15710&amp;YEAR=2022">0.60</a></td>
         <td class="week">7</td>
         <td class="salary">$3</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">RFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">8.06</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="eventablerow newposition ">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=14840" title="Salary: $2, Notes: RFA, Year Signed: 2021, Week 17: at Raiders Sun 4:05 p.m. ET" class="position_wr">Aiyuk, Brandon SFO WR<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsOld.svg" alt="recent news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="recent news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a></td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=14840&amp;YEAR=2022">26.70</a></td>
         <td class="week">9</td>
         <td class="salary">$2</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">RFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2021</td>
         <td class="drafted">2.16 (2021)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddtablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=13172" title="Salary: $1, Notes: UFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: at Titans Thu 8:15 p.m. ET" class="position_wr">Brown, Noah DAL WR<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsOld.svg" alt="recent news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="recent news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a></td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=13172&amp;YEAR=2022">1.70</a></td>
         <td class="week">9</td>
         <td class="salary">$1</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">UFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">BB $77</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="eventablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=15779" title="Salary: $3, Notes: RFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: vs Vikings Sun 4:25 p.m. ET" class="position_wr">Doubs, Romeo GBP WR<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsOld.svg" alt="recent news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="recent news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a> (R) </td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=15779&amp;YEAR=2022">5.00</a></td>
         <td class="week">14</td>
         <td class="salary">$3</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">RFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">2.11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddtablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=14127" title="Salary: $2, Notes: RFA, Year Signed: 2021, Week 17: vs Dolphins Sun 1:00 p.m. ET" class="position_wr">Meyers, Jakobi NEP WR<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsNew.svg" alt="new news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="new news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a> (<span class="warning injurystatus" title="Questionable">Q</span>)</td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=14127&amp;YEAR=2022">16.80</a></td>
         <td class="week">10</td>
         <td class="salary">$2</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">RFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2021</td>
         <td class="drafted">9.01 (2021)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="eventablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=15762" title="Salary: $3, Notes: RFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: at Ravens Sun 8:20 p.m. ET" class="position_wr">Pickens, George PIT WR<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsOld.svg" alt="recent news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="recent news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a> (R) </td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=15762&amp;YEAR=2022">4.90</a></td>
         <td class="week">9</td>
         <td class="salary">$3</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">RFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">1.11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddtablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=14992" title="Salary: $1, Notes: UFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: vs Saints Sun 1:00 p.m. ET" class="position_wr">Watkins, Quez PHI WR<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsNew.svg" alt="new news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="new news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a></td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=14992&amp;YEAR=2022">0.00</a></td>
         <td class="week">7</td>
         <td class="salary">$1</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">UFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">FCFS</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="eventablerow newposition ">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=14137" title="Salary: $1, Notes: UFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: vs Jets Sun 4:05 p.m. ET" class="position_te">Fant, Noah SEA TE<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsNew.svg" alt="new news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="new news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a> (<span class="warning injurystatus" title="Questionable">Q</span>)</td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=14137&amp;YEAR=2022">6.00</a></td>
         <td class="week">11</td>
         <td class="salary">$1</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">UFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">BB $101</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddtablerow">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=11647" title="Salary: $2, Notes: RFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: vs Browns Sun 1:00 p.m. ET" class="position_te">Thomas, Logan WAS TE<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsOld.svg" alt="recent news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="recent news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a></td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=11647&amp;YEAR=2022">11.60</a></td>
         <td class="week">14</td>
         <td class="salary">$2</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">RFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">7.06</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="eventablerow newposition ">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=13898" title="Salary: $1, Notes: UFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: at Packers Sun 4:25 p.m. ET" class="position_pk">Joseph, Greg MIN PK<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsOld.svg" alt="recent news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="recent news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a></td>
         <td class="points"><a href="https://www48.myfantasyleague.com/2022/options?L=51913&amp;O=08&amp;PLAYER_ID=13898&amp;YEAR=2022">5.00</a></td>
         <td class="week">7</td>
         <td class="salary">$1</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">UFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">FCFS</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddtablerow newposition ">
         <td class="player"><a href="player?L=51913&amp;P=0506" title="Salary: $1, Notes: UFA, Year Signed: 2022, Week 17: vs Bills Mon 8:30 p.m. ET" class="position_def">Bengals, Cincinnati CIN Def<img src="https://www.mflscripts.com/ImageDirectory/script-images/newsNone.svg" alt="no news" style="cursor:pointer;pointer-events:all;" title="no news" class="playerPopupIcon"></a></td>
         <td class="points"> ‐ </td>
         <td class="week">10</td>
         <td class="salary">$1</td>
         <td class="contractstatus">UFA</td>
         <td class="contractinfo">2022</td>
         <td class="drafted">FCFS</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```